# Issue in setting up react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning react with bootstrap by following a tutorial here:

[react-bootstrap getting started](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction)

The installation step says :

```
npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap
```

When I run this command I am getting warnings like this:

```
npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap
npm WARN bootstrap@4.2.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react@>=16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react-dom@>=16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @react-bootstrap/react-popper@1.2.1 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN prop-types-extra@1.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-context-toolbox@1.2.3 requires a peer of react@>=16.3.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-overlays@1.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-overlays@1.1.0 requires a peer of react-dom@>=16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-context-toolbox@2.0.2 requires a peer of react@>=16.3.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-transition-group@2.5.2 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-transition-group@2.5.2 requires a peer of react-dom@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-prop-types@0.4.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uncontrollable@6.0.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN create-react-context@0.2.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-popper@1.3.2 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN create-react-context@0.2.2 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.3
+ bootstrap@4.2.1
updated 2 packages in 1.788s
```

What is the correct way to install react bootstrap.

**Update**:

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This file is auto-generated using `npm init` command

Update:

After following steps of "first react app with CRA package" and then running `npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap`, I started seeing below error when I run `npm start`

```
>npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start H:\ReactJS\ReactJs-BootStrap\test\my-app
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-04T15_09_20_369Z-debug.log
```

Comment: these are warnings and not errors, so the package is installed. and each warning has a detailed description. go to `package.json` of your project and see the dependencies mentioned in warnings. if used CRA eject to see full list of packages

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, I added package.json which is auto-generated for me with npm-init command. So you mean to say I can ignore all these warnings and continue with next steps?

Comment: What? I did not get what you exactly mean. so you have not created your react app with `create-react-app` ? and do not have `react` `react-dom` packages yet ?

Comment: react should not be part of `devDependencies`. I highly recommend you for learning React start a project with `https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app` then install any css library you like

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, my bad I directly started using the commands given in that tutorial. now i understood the problem

Comment: ;) good, and also as I do not like bootstrap I recommend `https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage/` to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to react and bootstrap I recommend doing the following steps:

1 . Create your first react app with CRA package:

```
npx create-react-app my-first-app
```

2 . CD to my-first-app

3 . Install bootstrap

```
npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap
```

4.
Go to src folder and open index.js and paste the following to the top of the page:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css';
```

5 . Open App.js in the same folder and paste the following code (I am copy/pasting the original CRA app file and just added a simple Bootstrap button there):

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
        <Button>Test</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

6. You can see that you added a bootstrap button to the default create react app page. Yo can use the same pattern for adding other components.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I followed your steps and later ran `npm start`, now I am getting error as `'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: @learner I tested the steps on a clean installation and it worked fine. You can try running: rm -rf node_modules && npm install.  It may fix the issue with node module folder.

Comment: Also, if react-scripts is already listed in your package.json, please consider updating your Node.js to the latest stable version and run npm install again.

Comment: Can you please give me the commands to update the node js in windows

Comment: The easiest way is to download it from https://nodejs.org. It will update the current version for you.

Comment: The reason I suggest updating node is that I used npx instead of npm in step 1 and older versions do not support that.

Comment: I'm glad that it solved your issue. There is <Button>Test</Button> in the script. If you scroll to the very bottom of the page, there is a blue button right in the middle of the page. Sorry I added that to the bottom so it is not very visible.

Comment: Yes, it is visible in the end of page. By the way my issue is solved after running the command `npm install react-scripts --save`

Answer (score 0):

Test with jsx tag

```
<Button>Test</Button>
```

you have to import with

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```